# How to ensure File control has non-empty and valid file name in ASP.Net MVC Razor partail view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, razor, partial-views

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC 3 application with Razor view.

On click of a link, I open a JQuery Dialog which hosts a partail view. This partial view has a form with a file input control.

This form is bound to Model. But as there is no editorFor file(`HttpPostedFileBase`) I have manually palced HTML file input control.

How can I make sure that user can submit the form only if file input control has non-empty value and is a valid filename? I use Html.BeginForm to declare the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var file = document.getElementById('fileinputname');
    value = file.value;
    if(/* check value here */)
       return false;
})
```